# Is this highly discontinuous function Riemann integrable?

Tags: riemann-sum, riemann-integration, continuity

The function is given by  $$f(x)=sin(1/x)$$ if $x$ is irrational and $$f(x)=0$$ when $x$ is rational and $x$ belongs to $[0,1]$.

I have a feeling that such a highly discontinuous functions can't be Riemann integrated. I was trying to prove it using upper and lower sums. In any partition of the interval $[0,1]$ each sub interval will have rational and irrational numbers. So $$L(f)=sup(L(f,P))$$ is 0. But, what about $U(f)$. How do I find the maximum of the function at each of the sub intervals of the partition?

Comment: The criterion of Lebesgue is probably not something you can use?

Comment: @DanielFischer Actually, I was looking for a solution within the context of Darboux or Riemann integration without going into the Lebesgue criterion.

Comment: may be U(f) equals 1 because $ max(\sin (1/x))= 1$

Comment: No problem, it's just a little more work. Anyway, Lebesgue's criterion tells you $f$ is not Riemann integrable. Take a partition whose points are consecutive zeros of $\sin (1/x)$ and look at its refinements.